# Java Iterator hasNext strange behavior

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following code:

```
  Set<OWLNamedIndividual> individuals = reasoner.getInstances( tClass, false ).getFlattened();
  for(OWLNamedIndividual it1 : individuals)
       {            
     NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> names = reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues( it1, obj1 ); 
         System.out.println(it1.getIRI().getShortForm() + " has objects:");
     for(Node<OWLNamedIndividual> it2: names)
         {           
          Iterator iter=it2.iterator();
          while(iter.hasNext())
           {                          
            System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.println(iter.next().toString()); 
               System.out.println(iter.hasNext());                    
           }
         }
       }
```

that returns the following:

```
name has objects:
<http://www.test/#name>
     false
<http://www.test/#name2>
     false
```

The inner hasNext seams not working while the outer do. I need to check for the last iteration. What is the issue here ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem here. When you call `next()`, the value of `hasNext()` can change. The last time through it will print as `false`. In this case each outer collection appears to have only one element each.

Comment: But `hasNext` should print `true` after the first value, no ? Since it is the same `iterator`. And it is indeed looping on that `hasNext`.

Comment: No, because you've just called `next()`. When you've acquired the last `next()` value, `hasNext()` must now be false.

Comment: @AxelH The `for` loop has nothing to do with it. The issue is that he is calling `next()` and then `hasNext()`. If he was printing in the other order he would get `true` and then the value, instead of the value followed by `false`.

Comment: @AxelH Of course it's in a different iterator, but the question here is why did the inner iterator 'not work', in other words, fundamentally, why did `hasNext()` return `false` *at all*, and I have explained it.

Comment: _"Of course it's in a different iterator"_ that the part I didn't notice ... in my first comment I even said _"Since it is the same iterator"_ ... So the loop does matter as it iterate on `Node` giving the illusion to have one `Iterator` that reach two time the end. (I am cleaning your comment section)